# ESLint flagging functions as 'not defined' where they are loaded in the html

Tags: javascript, html, eslint

I'm working on a project where the environment (Moodle) doesn't support ES6 Harmony Modules correctly in all the recent browsers (looking at you Safari!). I have defined a lot of helper functions in a `common.js` file and the rest of the code in the `router.js` file, both of which are loaded using `<script>` elements in the html. As a result if I define a function called say `loadData()` in the `common.js` file and use it in the `router.js` file I get the linter error `'loadData' is defined but never used` in the first file and `'loadData' is not defined.` in the latter!

Whilst I could disable some of the ESLint rules they can be valuable in spotting issues. Is there a way to modifying my `.eslintrc.json` file so that ESLint is aware of these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just define them as global in eslintrc.